# How can I use expand() to include multiple levels of eager loaded properties for an entity with WCF Data Services for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-data-services

I'm using Silverlight 4.0 (so I need to make the call async and can't use EF directly) with a WCF Data Service and EF 4 to model the database.I want to make one call and have several levels of properties populated.

Say I have the following setup (but this could go deeper):
Accounts
 -- has zero or more Customers (and other properties)
    -- Customer has zero or more Addresses (and other properties)

I want to bring back 1 payload where Accounts, Customers, and Addresses are all eager loading and included in that one payload.

I want to get : Accounts.Expand("Customers").Where(a => a.Id == 1); This returns the payload with the account and customer populated. How do I include the Addresses in the same call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add Expand("Customers/Addresses"), you can add more of these, although there's a limit usually on the server. Something like 10 expanded entities should work, more might be problematic.

Comment: Thank you!! I had tried using a dot operator, but didn't think of the /. It now works the way I wanted it to.